# "you" in you people, you lot: its grammatical function

Tags: vocative

Are **you lot** and **you people** analyzed identically in each of their respective uses below? Or does **you** have a different function when the form is a direct address versus a non-address?

> You lot|you people, get to work!

versus:

> You lot|you people make me want to scream.

EDIT: To be clear, I'm not asking about the meaning but about what in old-school grammar would be called the "part of speech", except I'd like to know what **you** would be called *nowadays*, and if it is the same in both sample sentences, or different.

Comment: ***You lot*** is almost ALWAYS derogatory. ***You people*** is *usually* derogatory - but not in, for example, [***You people** are the next generation of those people fighting for freedom and for decency.*](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22you+people+are+the+next%22) Or *You people are the next best thing since sliced bread*, but no-one seems to have ever actually used that one in print. Syntactically there's no difference between ***you lot*** and ***you people***, but note that you can't *usually* treat ***lot*** and ***people*** as interchangeable.

Comment: Sorry if my question is unclear.  I'm asking for the grammatical difference between the direct address versus the non-direct-address, if there is one, in how the word **you** is analyzed.  Meaningwise, we're in agreement, on the guaranteed vs possibly derogatory implications.

Comment: I don't understand. The syntactic function of ***you*** here is the same whether it's followed by ***lot*** or ***people*** or neither, so why include those optional extra words (in apposition?) if they're not relevant?

Comment: The main "direct/indirect" difference is that in your first example, if you discard optional ***lot/people***, you can also discard the pronoun itself. It's quite normal to omit the implied subject *(**you**)* in imperatives in English, but you can't omit ***you*** from your second example.

Comment: ...actually, ***Make me want to scream*** IS potentially a valid imperative. But it's a fairly unlikely one - how often would you ask someone to do something that makes you want to scream?

Comment: You lot is only BrE. Not used in AmE speech.

Comment: Also, you lot OR you people, OR You lot, you people. No slash.

Comment: The character | is not a slash, @Lambie; it is often used  as a shorthand to separate variants.

Comment: @timR You can't be serious? What is the vertical bar ( | )?
"The vertical bar ( | ) -- also called the vertical line, vertical slash, pipe, pipe symbol or upright slash -- **is a symbol** used in mathematics, computing and other areas to represent a specific type of logic or operation, depending on its context." It is not a character, really. https://www.techtarget.com/whatis/definition/vertical-line-vertical-slash-or-upright-slash#:~:text=The%20vertical%20bar%20(%20%7C%20)%20%2D%2D,operation%2C%20depending%20on%20its%20context.

Comment: @Lambie: You're going down a rabbit-hole. Why are we talking about what a character is, and why are you parading one website as if it is the end-all-be-all authority on all things vertical-bar related? "A union type describes a value that can be one of several types. We use the vertical bar (|) to separate each type, so number | string | boolean is  the type of a value that can be a number, a string, or a boolean." https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/unions-and-intersections.html

Comment: @Lambie: Ditto.

Comment: It does not matter what you call it, it is not used in linguistics like that and certainly not without a space. A forward slash is better, but a comma is enough.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the terminology of [*CGEL*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Cambridge_Grammar_of_the_English_Language), "we" and "you" are *determinatives* (rather than pronouns) in phrases like "we students" and "you students". Here they occur in *determiner* function, much like "the" in "the students". They make the phrase definite, and also indicate that the speaker/addressee is included in the group of people referred to. Note that "they" cannot function in this way (**They students are complaining about the test*).

> You lot|you people, get to work!

Here "you lot" or "you people" is a noun phrase functioning as a vocative. Within the noun phrase, "you" is in determiner function.

> You lot|you people make me want to scream.

Here "you lot" or "you people" is a noun phrase functioning as the subject of the sentence. Within the noun phrase, "you" is in determiner function.

Comment: No, it's a vocative. Hey Joe, where're you going with that gun in your hand? [song\

Comment: The phrase is a vocative in the first example. I understand "vocative" to be a grammatical function within a clause/sentence, separate from subject etc.

Comment: These may be determinatives but that is not the full phrase.

Answer (score 0):

They can be considered identical, except…

… there is a tendency to read 'you people' as a category slur. Even though unintended, someone, somewhere, is going to read it the wrong way.

> You people, all you're interested in is money!
> You mean black people?
> No, honestly; I meant accountants.

'You lot' on the other hand, tends to just mean 'you people right in front of me right now, no-one outside this room is included'.

Answer (score 0):

They *are* quite different.

"*You lot*" refers to a specific collection of people, such as those the speaker is addressing. It might be said about a group of people that work in a particular place. It could be used to group people together who are not actually connected but just happen to be in a certain place at the same time. ("*You lot! Get out of my garden!*")

"*You people*" usually refers to people grouped by a particular identity such as a national identity or some other group identity. It could refer to someone's family.

I noticed a comment that said they are often or usually both derogatory - I don't entirely disagree; both can certainly be *disrespectful*. but it depends on the way they are said and who they are said to.

The reason "you people" is more often taken to be rude is because it can be used to make generalisations or promote stereotypes. For example, if you said to a person from an ethnic minority "*you people are [x]*" it would be taken that you think that about all people of the same ethnicity.

However, there are plenty of examples coming up in searches where "you people" is used quite respectfully. "*You are good people*" also comes up quite often.

"You lot" can be used playfully. You might say it about your family, for example ("*come on, you lot! We're going to be late!*").

Answer (score 0):

**"You lot" and "you people" function as vocatives.** Those are the people you are addressing. They mean the same thing but "You lot" is not used in AmE.

You lot, *get* to work!
You people, *get* to work! [get is imperative here]

For example:

> **The imperative is often used with a vocative. This is where you mention a person’s name or some other way of identifying the person to
> whom a command or request is being addressed.
>
> David, come here! Come
> here, David.
>
> Hey, you, stop talking!
>
> The vocative can be a proper
> noun, the pronoun you, or a noun phrase. The vocative can come before
> or after the main clause. A vocative forms a part of many questions.**

[What is vocative in English?](https://grammar.collinsdictionary.com/us/easy-learning/what-is-the-vocative-in-english)